# EOL Error with file path string in Python

Tags: python

I am trying to create a simple sting that points to a folder which contains a file on my C drive. The string is as follows:

```
filelocation = "C:\Documents\Folder\"
```

I am getting an EOL error which I think is being caused by the backslashes. Is it possible to have these backslashes in the string or is there another way of achieving this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python on Windows supports forward slashes:

```
filelocation = "C:/Documents/Folder/"
```

Alternatively, escape each of your `\` characters:

```
filelocation = "C:\\Documents\\Folder\\"
```

The reason you're getting the error is because of the final `\` character - Python is interpreting that as an escape sequence, and it thinks the string has not been terminated. To work around it, use one of my solutions above, or just omit the final `\`.

Comment: Or, use raw strings: `filelocation = r"C:\Documents\Folder\"`

Comment: Or if you never want to worry about file separators, use os.path.join: `import os; filelocation = os.path.join("C:", "Documents", "Folder")`

Answer (score 0):

On Windows: filelocation = "C:\\Documents\\Folder\\"

On Linux:   filelocation = "C:/Documents/Folder/"